# Modem CDMA ZTE AC2726 slow/delay detected about 3 minutesin Network Manager

Tags: network-manager

I have CDMA modem ZTE AC2726, when I connected to ubuntu, this modem wait until 3 minutes for detected in network manager, how to make this modem no delay for detected in network manager?

Answer (score 1):

Me too. I'm frustated. It seems that the ubuntu's linux kernel doesn't support ZTE AC2726 modem.

There is a patch for this problem. But I couldn't compile from the source..
http://skyisgrey.org/blog/mengoptimalkan-koneksi-modem-smart-zte-2726.html